# show alert box when user select non accepted file in danialfarid/ng-file-upload plugin

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload, ng-file-upload

- I am using [danialfarid/ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) plugin ,I set the ngf-select
  directive to .doc,.pdf extension. Its working fine.
- Problem is if a user select .png or jpg file, I want to show an alert
  box to user that this file type are not accepted. Thanks for in
  advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<div ngf-select ngf-pattern="'.png,.jpg'" ng-model="file">

<div class="alert" ng-show="file.$error === 'pattern'">file type is not accepted. Acceptable files: {{file.$errorParam}}</div>
```

Comment: Its not working , my html is : <div class="button" ngf-select ngf-accept="'.pdf,.docx,.doc,.pptx,.txt,.msg,.csv,.dat,.xlsx,.xls'" ng-model="file" ng-init="fileType = 'documents'"><i class="icon-documents"></i> Upload Document</div>
now if user select any type other then mention nfg-accept, an alert box show that file type is not accepted

Comment: by using you instruction, there is no restriction on file type. If I select file of any type , file being accepted and uploaded.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version and it is called ngf-pattern. ngf-accept is deprecated.

Comment: You need to verify if the file has error before uploading it, so in your upload js code check file.$error is null before uploading it.

Comment: " now if user select any type other then mention nfg-accept, an alert box show that file type is not accepted" isn't it what you asked for?

Comment: Yes ,its working fine now, thank you so much. Please keep your good work